# Mockito Test Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito

This is my first attempt with Mockito.

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationResponse startVisitForPatient(PatientBO patientBO,Locale locale) {
        ValidationResponse res = new ValidationResponse();
        if (patientManagementService.startVisit(patientBO.getId())){
            res.setStatus(MessageStatus.SUCCESS);
            res.setValue(messageSource.getMessage("success.message", null, locale));
        }
        else{
            res.setValue(messageSource.getMessage("failed.message", null, locale));
            res.setStatus(MessageStatus.FAILED);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

The service

```
@Transactional
    public boolean startVisit(long id) {
        Patient patient = patientRepository.findOne(id);
        Set<Encounter> encounters = patient.getEncounters();
        Encounter lastEncounter = null;
        Timestamp startVisitDate = null;
        Timestamp endVisitDate = null;
        if (encounters.iterator().hasNext()){
            lastEncounter = encounters.iterator().next();
            startVisitDate = lastEncounter.getStartVisitDate();
            endVisitDate = lastEncounter.getEndVisitDate();
        }
        if (lastEncounter == null || (endVisitDate != null && endVisitDate.after(startVisitDate))){
            Encounter newEncounter = new Encounter();
            newEncounter.setCreatedBy(userService.getLoggedUserName());
            newEncounter.setCreatedDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            newEncounter.setModifiedBy(userService.getLoggedUserName());
            newEncounter.setModifiedDate(newEncounter.getCreatedDate());
            newEncounter.setPatient(patient);
            newEncounter.setStartVisitDate(newEncounter.getCreatedDate());
            encounters.add(newEncounter);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Unit test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/root-context.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class Testing {


    @InjectMocks
    StaffVisitManagementController staffVisitManagementController;

    @Mock
    PatientManagementService patientManagementService;

    @Mock
    View mockView;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(staffVisitManagementController)
                .setSingleView(mockView)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartVisit() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/staff/visit/add").param("id", "1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string("success"));
    }
}
```

The test method indeed calls the controller. However I am not able to debug the service at this line

```
patientManagementService.startVisit(patientBO.getId()))
```

All it returns is just `false`.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: How exactly are you using Mockito here? I cannot see any mocking going on, so it's unclear why you've tagged this with Mockito.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted more complete code. Kindly see the updated questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mock something with Mockito, it mocks out *everything* to return some sort of default. For objects, this is `null`. For integers/doubles/etc, this is `0`, for booleans, `false`. See the [Mockito Docs](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing). So you can't step into it because it's not your class that's present in the controller under test, it's a generated proxy that is merely pretending to be your class (hence, *mocking*).

If you want to change the behaviour of your class, you will need to use Mockito to tell it to return different variables depending on what is passed to the method, or which test it's running in. e.g.

```
when(patientManagementService.startVisit(1)).thenReturn(true);
```

Would mean that, if any code using the mocked `PatientManagementService` calls `patientManagementService.startVisit(patientBO.getId())` where `patientBO.getId()` returns `1`, then it will return true, otherwise it will return `false`, which is the default answer.

In your case, I suspect you would be better off mocking out `patientRepository`, rather than `patientManagementService` if you want to be able to step into your service-layer code.

EDIT:

Roughly what I would suggest is:

```
private StaffVisitManagementController staffVisitManagementController;

private PatientManagementService patientManagementService;

@Mock
private PatientRepository patientRepository;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(patientRepository.findOne(1)).thenReturn(new Patient());
    patientManagementService = new PatientManagementService(patientRepository);
    staffVisitManagementController = new StaffVisitManagementController(patientManagementService);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(staffVisitManagementController)
            .setSingleView(mockView)
            .build();
}
```

Obviously, the name of repository class may be different, and you may be using field inject instead of constructor injection, etc, etc, but otherwise this should allow you to step into the `PatientManagementService` with the debugger. You will not be able to step into the `PatientRepository`, as that will be mocked.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you illustrate it using my code ?

Comment: Have a look at the edit, and I would strongly recommend going through the Mockito docs - it has a lot of features, more than i could reasonably cover in this answer.

Comment: sure, your answer has been very helpful. Thanks !